# How to create jwt token while at sign up?

Tags: node.js, express

I don't want to have the user require to sign up then proceed to logging in.

I currently have a /user POST route where I'm doing this:

```
// create a new user account 
router.post('/user', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
    res.json({success: false, msg: 'Please enter a userame, password and an email.'});
  } else {
    var newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: req.body.password,
      email: req.body.email
    });
    // save the user
    newUser.save(function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Username/email already exists.'});
      }else{
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user.', user: newUser });
    }
    });
  }
});
```

How can I implement so that when the user creates an account, it also creates a token to use for each API call. So they wouldn't need to authenticate right after signing up.

EDIT: could i put

```
var token = jwt.encode(user, secret);
```

in the success block?

Answer (score 0):

Well you answered it yourself. If you need it after success, just generate it there and put it in the response.